# MS Access SQL View

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a table from another table in MS Access using SQL...

The syntax i am using is

```
CREATE TABLE 
    new_table_name AS
SELECT 
    column1, 
    column2
FROM old_table;
```

however, I keep getting a syntax error:

> "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement".

Anyone can assist me or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing close that I can think of is [SELECT .... INTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx)

```
SELECT column1, column2
INTO new_table_name
FROM old_table;
```

Note that indexes and extended constraints outside of the type/length constraints will not be included in the new table.

Comment: It would be worth documenting that the new table wouldn't have any indexes.

Comment: @LarsTech - Good point. I think custom/extended constraints are also not included.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim sql as string
sql = "SELECT [column1], [column2] INTO [new_table_name] FROM [old_table]"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```